# Using DeflateStream in C++?

Tags: c#, c++, deflate

I'm currently trying to port some C# codes involving usage of DeflateStream into standard C++ without the support of .NET framework. One example of such function is:

```
public static byte[] ReadCompressed(this Stream stream)
{
    var reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
    int len = reader.ReadInt32();
    var array = new byte[len];
    var ds = new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
    ds.Read(array, 0, len);
    ds.Close();
    return array;
}
```

Just wondering, Is there an easy way to port the above code into C++? Thanks!

Comment: You will need either a 3rd party library like zlib (http://zlib.net/) or implement the deflate algorithm yourself, if you like wheel re-inventing.

Comment: @Joe: Is there a tutorial on how to use zlib under C++?

Comment: If you need to decompress data with zlib that was originally compressed with the .NET DeflateStream class (or vice-versa), you need to be careful. zlib requires a prefix and suffix to the data that DeflateStream does not generate. See http://tlzprgmr.wordpress.com/2010/03/17/net-deflatestreamzlib-compatibility/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use [zlib](http://zlib.net). The easiest way to do that in C++ is to use the [Boost wrapper for it](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/zlib.html).

I'm not entirely sure what your example does, but here's how to read in a zlib-compressed file and write its contents to stdout (adapted from an example in the docs):

```
namespace io = boost::iostreams;

std::ifstream file("hello.z", std::ios_base::binary);
io::filtering_streambuf<io::input> in;
in.push(io::zlib_decompressor());
in.push(file);
io::copy(in, std::cout);
```